# Group pandas dataFrame by a user defined span of months

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

What is the best approach to group data into winter seasons starting from Oktober to April ? With the evenly distributed frequencies of [`TimeGrouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) I don't get it to output the seasonal sum of wintermonths from seasons 1972/1973, 1973/1974 etc... Maybe a trivial thing, but I don't know how to do this without starting to write a overkill solution.

```
                 sd_x       sd_y
1972-10-31   0.000000   0.709677
1972-11-30   1.720838   4.366667
1972-12-31  15.893438   5.600000
1973-01-31   6.256230   6.548387
1973-02-28   0.653714  53.142857
1973-03-31   0.000000  70.354839
1973-04-30   0.000000  11.700000
1973-10-31   0.000000   0.096774
1973-11-30   0.000000   4.266667
1973-12-31   0.394652  53.419355
1974-01-31   4.540915  46.645161
1974-02-28   2.978056  35.571429
1974-03-31   0.000000   4.967742
1974-04-30   0.000000   0.000000
1974-10-31   0.000000   0.064516
1974-11-30   0.000000   1.000000
1974-12-31   5.585954  20.096774
1975-01-31  50.498147  24.580645
1975-02-28  35.906097  22.000000
1975-03-31   0.457109   5.483871
1975-04-30   0.000000   0.433333
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: 1972/1973 sum of sd_x, 1973/1974 sum of sd_x etc. I want to get the sum of sd for every winterseason starting from October to April. The index then could by look like 1973, 1974, 1975 .. But every yeah should contain the values from october to april

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pd.offsets.MonthBegin` to shift the months back by `4`

```
shifted_months = df.index - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(5)
shifted_months

DatetimeIndex(['1972-06-01', '1972-07-01', '1972-08-01', '1972-09-01',
               '1972-10-01', '1972-11-01', '1972-12-01', '1973-06-01',
               '1973-07-01', '1973-08-01', '1973-09-01', '1973-10-01',
               '1973-11-01', '1973-12-01', '1974-06-01', '1974-07-01',
               '1974-08-01', '1974-09-01', '1974-10-01', '1974-11-01',
               '1974-12-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

We can then use the `.year` attribute to `groupby` and `sum`

```
df.groupby(shifted_months.year).sum()

           sd_x        sd_y
1972  24.524220  152.422427
1973   7.913623  144.967128
1974  92.447307   73.659139
```

We can pretty up the indices with

```
df.groupby(shifted_months.year).sum().rename(lambda x: '{}/{}'.format(x, x + 1))

                sd_x        sd_y
1972/1973  24.524220  152.422427
1973/1974   7.913623  144.967128
1974/1975  92.447307   73.659139
```

Comment: you are tooo fast ;-)

Comment: sadly I cannot accept two answers. This answer has the better explaination and MaxU answer is a nice oneliner ! Thank you both for the fast answer !

Comment: @Manuel Sad for us too. :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
In [94]: df.groupby((df.index - pd.DateOffset(months=4)).year).sum()
Out[94]:
           sd_x        sd_y
1972  24.524220  152.422427
1973   7.913623  144.967128
1974  92.447307   73.659139
```

Comment: I  like `df.index - pd.DateOffset(months=4)` better!